# codeigniter flashdata success message returned failed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I updated some data and it returns to failed when it successfully update or not. 
 
Here is my controller code:

```
 $data['edit_cli'] = $this->clients_model->edit_cli();
if(!empty($data['edit_cli'])){
  $_SESSION['cli_updated'] = '<div class="alert alert-success cli_updated">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  Client Updated Successfully
  </div>';
  $this->session->mark_as_flash('cli_updated');
}
else{
  $_SESSION['cli_updated'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger cli_updated">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  Client Updated Failed
  </div>';
  $this->session->mark_as_flash('cli_updated');
}
```

what I want:
If data is updated successfully it returns only `Client Updated Successfully`

And If it can not be updated successfully it returns `Client Updated Failed`.

Is there a bug in my controller code, possibly my `if` conditions?

Here is my `model` code:

```
   function edit_cli(){
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
            $date = date('Y-m-d',time());

            $cli_id = $this->input->post('client_id');
            $data = array(
                'product_id' => $this->input->post('product_id'),
                'clientName' => $this->input->post('clientName'),
                'companyName' => $this->input->post('companyName'),
                'client_info_doc' => $date,
                'client_info_created_by' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
                );

            $this->db->where('client_id', $cli_id);
            $this->db->update('tbl_client_info', $data);    

        }
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the `if` condition. What exactly does the model return?

Comment: it couldn't return `if` statement. after updated it returns only `else` statement.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the model code.

Comment: @DFriend , Please check my question. I included model code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from model ! Please return the result from your model. So, please replace this line at the end line in your model code then see what happens .
.

```
    $result  =  $this->db->update('tbl_client_info', $data);  

    return $result;
```

For that change this line in your contoller's if condition

```
    if($data['edit_cli']){
         //your code here
     }else{
       //your code here
    }
```

because you r returning 0 or 1 always .That's why result is not empty !

Comment: now `if` condition returns successfully. but `else` couldn't if my field is empty.

Comment: Hey bro was it ok now ?

Comment: no brother. If I couldn't updated data it will be shown Updated Failed. But Now it returns only Successfully msg.

Comment: Have change your controller as suggested ?

Comment: lets talk in chat !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183481/discussion-between-m-alim-and-sabbir).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider changing the `if` logic a little. But as M. Alim pointed out, you must return something from the model.  Change the last line of the model to

```
return $this->db->update('tbl_client_info', $data);
```

The method `$this->db->update()` will return TRUE or FALSE.

The code

```
if(!empty($data['edit_cli'])){
    // successful message
} else {
    // failed message
}
```

should be changed to

```
if($data['edit_cli'] === TRUE){
    // successful message
} else {
    // failed message
}
```